# How can I create guides in Illustrator that are at any angle, not horizontal or vertical?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, grids, guides

I searched a lot and I have not found how to put these grids oblique. Can someone help me? Thank you very much!

[image]

Comment: It's very important that you tell us what software this is.

Comment: sorry! Illustrator

Answer (score 4):

If you are working in Adobe Illustrator then you can draw any line or shape and then go to `View > Guides > Make Guides` to change that shape into a guide. Items will snap to these guides in exactly the same was as guides made in the 'normal' way. This works with any shape which means you can even create curved guides.